# Decript Jasypt encrypted information

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, encryption, jasypt

I am encrypting an object with below entry using Spring and Hibernate. As I have salt and password is it possible to decryption the information back to plain text?

```
<bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
    class="org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="registeredName" value="hibernateStringEncryptor" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
    <property name="saltGenerator">
        <bean class="org.jasypt.salt.FixedStringSaltGenerator">
            <property name="salt" value="1" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bride")
@TypeDef(name = "encryptedString", typeClass = org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = { @Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName", value = "hibernateStringEncryptor") })

public class BrideDetails {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MD5 encryption then no one can be do, but if you use your given algorithm then you can....

Comment: Correct. I am using Jasypt. using http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt-hibernate3/1.9.0/org/jasypt/hibernate/type/EncryptedStringType.html to encrypt. how to find this is MD5 or not. (I am New to encryption)

Comment: this will help you for your web portal  http://sourceforge.net/p/jasypt/mailman/jasypt-users/?viewmonth=200906